# Openalpr Languages error

Tags: camera

I tried example of python code in openalpr.

> from openalpr import Alpr
>   alpr = Alpr("us", "/etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf", "/home/pi/openalpr/runtime_data/")
>   if not alpr.is_loaded():
>       print("Error loading OpenALPR")
>       sys.exit(1)
>   alpr.set_top_n(20)
>   alpr.set_default_region("md")
>   results = alpr.recognize_file("/path/to/image.jpg")
>   i = 0
>   for plate in results['results']:
>       i += 1
>       print("Plate #%d" % i)
>       print("   %12s %12s" % ("Plate", "Confidence"))
>       for candidate in plate['candidates']:
>           prefix = "-"
>           if candidate['matches_template']:
>               prefix = "*"
>    print("  %s %12s%12f" % (prefix, candidate['plate'], candidate['confidence']))
>   Call when completely done to release memory
>   alpr.unload()

when I build this code I get this error

> Warning: You are running an unsupported version of Tesseract.
>   Expecting at least 3.03, your version is: 3.02.02
>   Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/lus.traineddata
>   Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
>   Failed loading language 'lus'
>   Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
>   Segmentation fault

How to solve this error? Default path is /usr/local/share/tessdata/. I want change to defferent path where I installed path. Then this error can solve. How to change defult path?

Comment: This is for when cording python code error other question is when derectly use library name for example alpr imagepath.jpg. These two are defferent @goldilocks

Comment: The error, `Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory`, is exactly the same and has exactly the same solution.  You can check the current value with `echo $TESSDATA_PREFIX`.  If there's nothing, or the wrong thing, you have not set it correctly.